# ngx-bootstrap to show Timepicker placeholder by default

Tags: angular

I'm currently using ngx-bootstrap Timepicker for my Angular 4 app. [http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#/timepicker]

The problem: I need to show the placeholders (HH and MM) as default when the template is generated.

Currently, when I set the Date ngModel to null or undefined, it will set default hours and minutes (e.g 08 : 00) instead of (HH : MM)

I use it as below in html

```
<timepicker [(ngModel)]="mytime"></timepicker>
```

Setting the Date below in typescript

```
mytime: Date = null;
```

Is there any way on how can I achieve it without modifying the Timepicker bootstrap files?

Thank you!

Comment: Try not setting any default value to the field.
mytime: Date = null; should be mytime: Datel;

Answer (score 0):

You can try initializing mytime variable as below

mytime:Date;

It is working for me . Try it and let me know if it works .

Answer (score 0):

Only set the data type of mytime, i.e
 mytime: Date;

Answer (score 0):

The **mytime** variable has to be of type **Date**. The snippet below would initialize your timepicker field correctly.

```
mytime: Date = new Date();
```